# Cannot resolve method 'postDelayed(anonymous java.lang.Runnable)'

Tags: android

So I've imported android.os.Handler (it says android 33 which is the one I'm using) but after importing it the runnable goes grey. It says Cannot resolve method 'postDelayed(anonymous java.lang.Runnable)'

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, Login.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

This is my code. idk why it isn't working

Answer (score 0):

[`postDelayed()` takes two parameters](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/Handler?hl=en#postdelayed): the `Runnable`, plus the delay period in milliseconds. You are passing only the `Runnable`. You need to add the second parameter.

You also do not need the `Handler`. [`postDelayed()` is a method on `View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/View?hl=en#postdelayed). So, you can call it only any convenient widget from your layout.

Comment: thanks this worked after adding a second parameter